# Iterating through a findall div with beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

Using `Beautiful Soup` I would like to iterate through each of the `div data-search-sol-meta={blah:blah...}` and print all of the contents inside of the div.

```
page = requests.get('https://www.seek.com.au/python-junior-jobs', headers=header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

section = soup.find('div', {'class':'_3MPUOLE'})

for div in section.findAll('div.data-search-sol-meta'):  #<-- having difficulty with this
    print(div)
    print("\n")
```

**Question:**
How can I go through the website and iterate through all of the div.data-search-sol-meta so that I can print and further process the contents of the div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing yor `for` loop to

```
for div in section.select('div[data-search-sol-meta]'):
```

and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the page you are trying to sparse and I'd suggest using `results = soup.find_all('article')`